# discord.js Как разрешить нажимать кнопку только тому пользователю, который был указан в параметре команды?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, бот, discord-api

Как разрешить нажимать или использовать кнопку только тому пользователю, который был указан в параметре команды?

Что я хочу получить:

1. пользователь1 использует слеш-команду, указывает в ней параметр с пользователем2
2. отправляется сообщение, кнопку может нажать или использовать только пользователь2
3. сообщение обновляется после нажатия кнопки пользователем2

bite.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

const emotionHitPicture= [
    'https://c.tenor.com/MKjNSLL4dGoAAAAC/bite-cute.gif',
    'https://c.tenor.com/4j3hMz-dUz0AAAAC/anime-love.gif',
    'https://c.tenor.com/Sp7yE5UzqFMAAAAC/spank-slap.gif',
    'https://c.tenor.com/0uRmrUvyZFEAAAAC/vamp-vampire-bite.gif',
    ];

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('bite')
        .setDescription('Укусить')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('пользователь').setDescription('Выбери пользователя, которого хочешь укусить').setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('Primary')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            );

            return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [{
            description: `${interaction.user} укусил(-а) ${interaction.options.getUser('пользователь')}, будем думать, что не больно!`,
            image: {
                url: `${emotionHitPicture[Math.floor(Math.random() * emotionHitPicture.length)]}`,
            },
            }],
            components: [row],
        });
    }
};
```

interactionCreate.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',

    execute(interaction) {

        if(interaction.isButton()) {

            if (interaction.customId === 'primary') {
                return interaction.update({
                    embeds: [{
                    description: `будем думать, что не больно!`}],
                    components: []
                })  
            } else return
        }

        console.log(`da ${interaction.options.getUser('пользователь')}`)

        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.`);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

bite.js =>
Вы должны получить пользователя, который указан в .addUserOptions, и занести его в коллектор компонентов, указав что i.user.id должен обязательно равняться target.id.

```
        const target = interaction.options.getMember("пользователь")        
        const time = 1000 * 60 * 3
        const filter = i =>
            i.user.id === target.id && ['button_name'].includes(i.customId)

    const message = await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [],
            components: [],
            fetchReply: true,
        })

    message.createMessageComponentCollector(filter, time)
```

interactionCreate => Не изменный.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Изменил, добавил информацию.